# The $5\times 5$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $1$ if $j$ is a multiple of $i$, and $0$ otherwise

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

The $5\times 5$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $1$ if $j$ is a multiple of $i$, and $0$ otherwise.

I know that I’m supposed to show the work I’ve done, but I just have no idea what to do with this.

I know what $5\times 5$ means, and I know the $i$ terms are the ones running horizonally, and $j$ terms running vertically, but I just need help visualizing how they are being multiplied together, or what the question is actually asking

I have the answer in the back of the book, i just need help understanding.

Comment: can you write out the full matrix. you can use the pmatrix{} command in latex.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the exact question is? Are you having trouble determining the form of the matrix?

Comment: The first two lines are all my book says, i guess the question is to "write down the following matrices" with the information given

Comment: If $i=1$, then all $j$s are multiples of $i$. If $i=2$, then only $2,4$ are multiples of $i$. Etc, etc. This gives you a list of $(i,j)$ pairs satisfying the condition. Now create a $5 \times 5$ matrix with $1$s in these places and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: what is the entry if $j$ is not a multiple of $i?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix, together with row and column numbers, is this one:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
&\begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5\end{array}\\ \hline
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
5
\end{array}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&\color{magenta}1&0\\
0&0&1&\color{brown}0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&\color{red}1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}$$

The magenta $1$ is the $(2,4)$ entry; in other words, it’s the $(i,j)$ entry when $i=2$ (row $2$) and $j=4$ (column $4$). Since $4$ is a multiple of $2$, it’s a $1$. The brown entry under it is the $(3,4)$ entry, in row $3$, column $4$; since $4$ is *not* a multiple of $3$, it’s $0$. And the red entry in the lower righthand corner is the $(5,5)$ entry, in row $5$, column $5$; since $5$ is a multiple of itself, this entry is a $1$.

All of the other entries can be explained similarly.